# How to change image size depending window size

Tags: html, css, image

I'm working on my first website. I've created a big image banner and it's working but I have a problem with setting his height. When I try to do this with % height my banner disappears. I would like to make it responsive and make it shorter when the window is small. Here is my code and CSS styles for container div:

```css
    #slides-container
{
 width: 100%;
 height: 400px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
}
#slides-container>img
{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
    max-width: 100%
}
#slides-container>.arrow-button
{
 position: absolute;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 25px;
 top: 200px;
 background: none;
 color: white;
 font-size: 20px;
}
#slides-container>#button-next:hover
{
 box-shadow: 10px 0px 20px 0px black;
}
#slides-container>#button-previous:hover
{
 box-shadow: -10px 0px 20px 0px black;
}
#slides-container>#button-previous
{
 position: relative;
 float: right;
}
.slide-fade
{
 animation-name: fade;
 animation-duration: 0.2s;
}
@keyframes fade
{
 from{opacity: 0.4}
 to{opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<div id="slides-container">
        <img class="slides slide-fade img-responsive" src="img/1.jpg"/>
        <img class="slides slide-fade img-responsive" src="img/2.jpg"/>
        <img class="slides slide-fade img-responsive" src="img/3.jpg"/>
        <img class="slides slide-fade img-responsive" src="img/4.jpg"/>
        <img class="slides slide-fade img-responsive" src="img/5.jpg"/>
        <button class="arrow-button" onclick="plusIndex(-1)" id="button-next">&#10094;</button>
        <button class="arrow-button" onclick="plusIndex(1)" id="button-previous">&#10095;</button>
   </div>
```

Comment: I think you forgot to add the CSS code.

Comment: why don't you try class="img-responsive" of bootstrap

Comment: Soryy don't know why I can't edit and include my CSS wait a minute. img-responsive doesn't work. It is still not responsive in vertical..

Comment: Ok it is all with CSS. Everything works good but it is problem only with height. I've tried before even a moment ago img-responsive and it isn't still responsive in vertical..

Comment: If i change in #slides-container: height to % image disappears

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vh` instead of `%`. It is the other way to make the height responsive in every view height. Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport*